# 1995 Honda Civic dx Overheats and does not want to go over 35 mph when overheating also has a burn smell

Tags: honda, civic, smell, overheating

I have had my car for over 7 years 
Rebuilt transmission and fixed many things over the years
put to much money into it. I really need help and dont know what to do ...
I have a 1995 Honda Civic Dx...automatic

My car Over heats and does not want to go over 35 mph / 40 mph when over heating 
also has a burn smell no mater how hard I push on gas it does not wanna go over... seems like brakes also get hard to.. I do know there is a burning smell coming from power steering pump Fluid when I open the lid to smell it ... issue does not happen much at night always in the day time when temps are really hot.... Does anyone know what is causing this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very much like a fault with your water pump seizing, as it comes across as temperature related. A quick check by your favourite mechanic should tell you more. The power steering fluid will have a 'sort of pungent smell' as normal, which can easily be confused with being 'burnt'.